# ASP.Net MVC web application, Login Failure when using Chrome and success When I Use IE

Tags: asp.net, authentication, browser

I have created a new web application and created a role and a user in startup.cs using VS2019. When I use Internet Explorer my login attempt is successful, when I use Chrome it fails. Sometimes with Chrome is also successful but does not go to return url and gets back to login page!
Any Idea?

Comment: post some code.

Comment: Try incognito mode

Comment: Thank you! It works! What's the reason? Now it works, even in normal mode (after using incognito mode for one time).

Answer (score 0):

I used another machine using Chrome to browse the application, it was OK. May be there is something in cache on previous machine!